# Jquery next() Problem

Tags: jquery

i have this:

```
<div class="selection">
 <a class="current" href="#">1</a>
 <div class="class">text</div>
 <a href="#">2</a>
 <div class="class">text</div>
 <a href="#">4</a>
 <div class="class">text</div>
 <a href="#">5</a>
</div>
```

i want to select the very next a element after a.current.
I did this, but it doenst work.

...

```
$(".selection a.current").next("a").hide();
```

i also tried

```
$(".selection").children("a.current").next("a").hide();
```

...
Arent all the a´s inside .selection siblings and therefore be accesable with the next() selector? I wonder, because it works when i remove the div elements between them.

Would be great if someone knows why this is not working ;).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From [jQuery API browser](http://api.jquery.com/next/):

> Get the immediately following sibling
>   of each element in the set of matched
>   elements, optionally filtered by a
>   selector.

That's not the immediately following sibling. You could try using `nextAll` and adding a `:first` selector:

```
$(".selection a.current").nextAll("a:first").hide();
```

Comment: thank you, i understand now...but one more thing..if i would like to select the previous a element (assuming the last a in the selection had the class current)..how would that work. i tried:

$(".selection a.current").prevAll("a:first").hide();

shouldnt this also work the other way arround?

btw: i am trying to build a list that is selectable with the arrow keys.

Comment: Try using :last instead of :first in that case. Also, when an answer has answered your question, make sure to click the check mark next to it :)

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
.nextAll("a:first");
```

And to get the previous:

```
.prevAll("a:first");
```

Demo online: http://jsbin.com/ayasa

Comment: ...hoooooly snap. I've been wishing there was a site like JS Bin for a while now, but never looked because I never thought it could really happen. Thanks :o

Comment: @Matchu: It's great for quickly working up jQuery examples :)

Comment: ...just now used it in another answer. My life is so much happier now.

Comment: Congrats :) You'll grow to love it. I believe they're releasing a version 2 here before too long. The main developer is a jQuery Evangelist.