# .parent().next() not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I do:

```
$("a").on("click", function(e) {
    $(this).parent().find("ul").toggleClass("closed opened");
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

It works but it will target all uls of the parent

so I am doing

```
$("a").on("click", function(e) {
    $(this).parent().next("ul").toggleClass("closed opened");
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

But this doesn't work, I get no errors at all.

If I do the following works on JSFiddle using the html used here:

```
$("a").on("click", function(e) {
    $(this).next("ul").toggleClass("closed opened");
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

It doesn't make sense. I need to target the first `<ul>` child of the parent element that I am clicking.

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="">Text</a>
     <ul class="closed">
        <li><a href="">Two</a>
           <ul class="closed">
              <li><a href="">Three</a>
                <ul class="closed">
                   <li><a href="">Four</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
           </ul>
         </li>
     </ul>
   </li>
</ul>

.closed {
    display: none;
}

.opened {
    display: block;
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3d3nzj42/1/) with the html used in the example

**UPDATE**

> Thanks to comment due to my real html having a `<span>` element I had to use
>   `.nextAll()`

**Actual html**

```
<ul>
  <li>
     <a href="">Text</a>
     <span></span>
     <ul class="closed">
        <li>
           <a href="">Two</a>
           <span></span>
           <ul class="closed">
              <li>
                <a href="">Three</a>
                <span></span>
                <ul class="closed">
                   <li><a href="">Four</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
           </ul>
         </li>
     </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
```

[This is the JSFidle with the real html](https://jsfiddle.net/3d3nzj42/8/)

Comment: parent of `a` is `li` which doesn't have a `ul` "next"

Comment: you mean that you need to target the `ul` element of the parent or what? please define by an example what you want to target.

Comment: it's a nested ul, there is a <ul> inside the li

Comment: Disadvantage of jQuery is you don't get an error if you get no result. Is there a `next("ul")`? What is the value of its length?

Comment: @MohammedElSayed updated the question with jsFiddle

Comment: As a side note: there is no semantic value of making those elements `<a>` elements, since you don't use them for navigating and they don't work even without JavaScript, so it would be better to use different elements and maybe even add them from code, or at least hide them in a non-JS environment.

Comment: @GolezTrol the above html is an example, I thought of using buttons in real life, yet it's a visual effect not to click to go somewhere, however they are links when js is not activated, therefore they are accessible

Comment: @rob.m: I've an answer for you down below :)

Comment: @rob.m Actual functionality in non-JS. Good. ^.^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

what you are looking for is `siblings()` instead of `next()`

```
$("a").on("click", function(e) {
    $(this).siblings("ul").toggleClass("closed opened");
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

The reason why `next` is not working with you is in the way that you tried to use it.
you have used `parent()` first, then asked to get the `next()` element of type `ul`, and this doesn't match the way `next` should work.

cause in your DOM structure, the `next` element after going up to the `parent` will be your anchor tag, and `next` will only match with **just** the first element in your dom, not with the first element that matches with your selector, and this is the root cause of your mis-usage.

consider the official description of how `next` with a selector is working:

> The method optionally accepts a selector expression of the same type that we can pass to the $() function. If the immediately following sibling matches the selector, it remains in the newly constructed jQuery object; otherwise, it is excluded.

`nextall` will also do the trick.

Comment: Why is that? Why isn't `.next` enough?

Comment: That's it. ! Thanks a lot

Comment: @FelixKling that is exactly why I've asked the question, check my JSFiddle, I don't understand why

Comment: @rob.m: Uh? You said it works with `.next`: "*If I do the following works:"*

Comment: @FelixKling it does on JSFiddle, but not on my live site

Comment: @rob.m: kindly check my updated clarification above, hope it clarify what is going on for you :)

Comment: @rob.m: Then the document structure in your example is different than it is on your actual site. You should update your example.

Comment: *"The reason why next is not working with you is in the way that you tried to use it. you have used parent() first,"* But the OP also did this: `$(this).next("ul").toggleClass("closed opened");`, which worked. If `.siblings` works but `.next` doesn't, then there must be another element between the `<a>` and the `<ul>` element, which is the actual problem.

Comment: @FelixKling there you go, copy/paste from my real html https://jsfiddle.net/3d3nzj42/7/

Comment: after checking your actual html, my clarification is still correct. your `next` element to the anchor is a `span` element, and not a `ul`, so by using `siblings` it will look for your selector in all siblings, but `next only gets the first item and stops.

Comment: @rob.m: This is the solution you should use: [Efficient, concise way to find next matching sibling?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4933275/218196)

Comment: *"the next element after going up to the parent will be your anchor tag"* That's incorrect, the next sibling is the following `li` element. The problem I have with this answer is that it was pure guess (and didn't provide any explanation initially). `.next` was a correct solution for the original problem statement.

Comment: @FelixKling are you saying that the problem is due to having an extra el <span>? Because that's the only difference, yet the <span> is a children of .parent("ul") of the clicked el just as much as it is its next <ul>, no?

Comment: @rob.m: Yes, that's exactly the issue. Have a look at the documentation of `.next` again. `.next` selects the *next sibling* *if and only if* it matches the provided selector. Since the next element is a `<span>` element  it doesn't match the selector `ul`, so it is not selected. OTOH, `.nextAll` will find *all* following siblings that match the selector. This has been asked on SO quite often, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/q/2089089/218196 .

Comment: @FelixKling is see, thanks a lot, so the real answer is to use .nextAll for my real scenario

Comment: @FelixKling yes i confirm, it works. .nextAll() is what I needed. I will leave this as accepted tho as it answers my first question. Thanks tho

Answer (score 2):

The parent of the clicked `a` element is a `li` element. The next siblings of the parent `li` elements can only be other `li` elements. So the script simply fails to select the target element and it actually makes sense as `.next` only selects the very next [matching] siblings.

Fortunately you have a working version!

Comment: I am confused, I am clicking on <a> which has a parent <li> which has 2 childs the <a> that I click and a <ul> that I want to target, using .parent() on the <a> should work no?

Comment: @rob.m: `.next` selects the next **sibling**, not a **child**. https://api.jquery.com/next/ . See this image for an explanation of DOM node relationships: http://felix-kling.de/images/DOM_relationship.png .

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$("a").on("click", function(e) {
    $(this).closest("ul").toggleClass("closed opened");
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Objective:

> I need to target the **first child** of the parent element that I am clicking

#### Try:

> `$(this).next("ul").toggleClass("closed opened");`

`<a>` or `$(this)` has `<ul>` as a sibling, so it's a matter of using the correct method when referring directly from `$(this)` that being `.next()`. There's no need to reference the parent in this situation as I understand it.

<kbd>[**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/zer00ne/kcdat38u/1/)</kbd>